# Interstitial ad failed to load: Cache Error facebook audience network

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I have a problem implementing fan interstitial I have done everything correctly 
but when I want to test the code I got this error

```
com.example.smail E/Gbody: Interstitial ad failed to load: Cache Error
```

this is my implementation

```
   if(FBORAD==0) {


        interstitialAd = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.fb_inter));
        interstitialAd.loadAd();

        Activity activity = this; // must be an Activity


        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad displayed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");


            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial dismissed callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                // Ad error callback
                Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
                // Show the ad
                interstitialAd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
                Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
            }
        });




    }
```

this is my code and when i run the app got the error above 
can someone help me with that 
i searched everywhere but sadly facebook not providing a good documentation

Answer (score -1):

This might happen because your test cache period is over.

Go to the FB console and click your test device to refresh the cache.

Once refreshed, this error should be gone.